# What do you call your grand-father's brother? (grand- v great-)

Tags: kinship-terms

Your father's father is called your grand-father, yet your father's uncle is typically called your great-uncle (or so it seems with anybody I converse with). Why the inconsistency?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no inconsistency. *Grand* is always used for "parent of a parent". Beyond that, *great-* and *grand-* mean the same thing. Your grandfather's brother is your great-uncle, grand-uncle, or granduncle.

It has been brought up in the comments that *granduncle* (written) is archaic everywhere, while *grand-uncle* (spoken) is archaic in Britain. I'm not sure if it's archaic in America too (I swear I've heard it), but you will not go wrong if you always use *great-uncle*.

Comment: Curious, what does the "once removed" or "twice removed" mean?

Comment: once removed = 1 generation above or below. So my first cousin's son is my first cousin, once removed. *That* person's son is my first cousin, twice removed.

Comment: aaand i just realized that doesn't apply here. not sure what i was thinking, but it's just grand uncle in this case. no removal. sorry about that.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it. Not sure why you got downvoted.

Comment: well, it was wrong at first. no worries :)

Comment: -1. You are incorrect. He is quite simply your 'great uncle'. The term 'once-removed' is used to indicate a generational distance between cousins. So you would, for example, call your father's cousin your 'cousin once removed'. Or your own cousins would be 'cousins once removed' to your children. I suppose you could call your 'great uncle' your 'uncle once removed', but since the term 'great-uncle' is available, it is not normally used.

Comment: @ws2 yes, i already corrected my answer ...

Comment: So, asides from grandparents', great- and grand- are interchangeable? I never knew that! :-)

Comment: @kguest yes, except for great-grandparents. *grand-grandparents* is not used, at least i haven't heard of it. it's also worth noting that you rarely hear (in the US at least) either "great" or "grand" other than in *grandparent*. people often will call their great-uncle their "uncle", and same for other great-relatives.

Comment: @sgroves I have tried to remove my down vote but the system won't let me. The term grand-uncle is nowadays archaic. The most recent reference the OED has for it is dated 1881. The OED does not even recognise 'granduncle' without a hyphen.

Comment: @ws2 i'm sure you're right; i've never seen granduncle, but it's in some dictionaries so i listed it. seems weird that grand-uncle/grand uncle is considered archaic though - i'm sure i've heard it used. maybe this is a regional difference?

Comment: @sgroves It may be used in America, or some parts of America  (I think the South is more likely to retain old forms isn't it?). But I have never heard it used in post-1945 Britain, though I have read it in older documents. Others may disagree.

Comment: Minor points: Exceptions *are* inconsistencies, so if you say "*great-* and *grand-* mean the same thing, *except* in the case of parents of parents", then you're saying it's inconsistent. Worse, they don't really mean the same thing. You can't just use either one wherever you like. You never say great-grand-great-great-grandparent. Or grand-great-uncle. What I think you mean, and how the situation is conceptually more consistent, is that *grandparent* is its own first-class thing (not a one-level-higher parent), while *great-* is **always** a modifier to create a one-level-higher whatever.

Comment: @WS2 I've edited a minor detail, so you can now remove your vote. I think what happened is that sgroves fixed the error within the 5 minute grace period, so it didn't count as a separate edit, so your vote remained locked in.

Comment: @Daniel Thankyou. Hope that's done the trick.